# How to return raw php code?

Tags: php

I have this code for example:

```
ob_start();
echo "hello there";
$output = ob_get_contents();
return $output;
```

When I run it, I get back:

```
hello there
```

But how can I get back

```
echo "hello there";
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: I don't quite understand, why is the echo code the only one returned? are you only interested in returning echo calls?

Comment: `?>echo "hello there";<?php` - drop out of PHP mode and anything you type (PHP code or otherwise) shows for the world to see.

Comment: seems like You want to get code of some encoded php file by executing between ob_*  (:  if Yes, so it's not done like this.

Comment: @num8er: if you say it's not done like this - can you elaborate how it *is* done?

Comment: I mean if You want to get source of obfuscated-encoded script, so You've to analyze file manually and do complex variable mapping and etc. I cannot show it's long procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To output arbitrary text as-is you can close the PHP script and then reopen it.  Anything between the closing and opening tags is output as-is

```
ob_start();
?>echo "hello there";
<?php
$output = ob_get_contents();
return $output;
```

Comment: yes, but this kind of 'script' will be useless - you cant run it

Comment: It's actually useful if you have a script that needs to generate a hard-coded script ;)

Comment: Can you conditionally drop in and out of PHP?

Comment: Yes you can @Taapo just drop out in the body of an if/else statement

Comment: @TheH Problem with that approach is that you have to echo twice in an if/else statement, not? If you use <? if ($statement == true) { ?>echo "hello";<? } else { echo "hello"; } ?> -- I would love to prevent the double work. The following won't work, but I'm wondering if there is an other way? <? if ($statement == true) { ?> } echo "hello"; { <? } ?>

Answer (score 2):

`ob_get_contents` will return the echoed output, so you can't use it to show actual code.

To simply print out code, I would try this:

```
$code = file_get_contents('your_code.php');
echo "<pre>{$code}</pre>";
```

Also you can write you code separatle as text and echo it or eval (if you need execution).

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

result:

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

Answer (score 1):

*By representing it as a string*:

```
ob_start();
$str = <<<STR
echo "hello there";
STR;
echo $str;
$output = ob_get_contents();
return $output;
```